# Implementing a string exclusion in regex

Tags: regex

What regex rule would drop the preceding "> " (greater than symbol followed by a space).

```
> Bay of Pigs
```

translates to

```
Bay of Pigs
```

I have tried:

```
[^>\s]
```

which has not worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use positive look-behind,

```
(?<=>\s).*
```

**Positive Look-behind**

> `(?<=...)` Ensures that the given pattern will match, ending at the
>   current position in the expression. The pattern must have a fixed
>   width. Does not consume any characters.

Concisely, it matches anything after `>` and a space character `\s`

[Click here for demo](https://regex101.com/r/f2io9H/1)

Comment: Can you explain what the `<=` means?

Comment: its `positive look-behind` I have added explanation.